# antd in react app but failed to compile

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

antd tutorial use in typescript

1. create react app ...ok
2. yarn add antd ...ok
3. import antd.css in App.css ...ok

but i'm met this error message

```
D:/8VSCode/vcjoo-ant/src/App.tsx
(16,10): Type '{ shape: "circle"; icon: string; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Button> & Pick<Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<AnchorButtonProps> & Pick<InferProps<{ type: any; shape: any; size: any; htmlType: any; ... 4 more ...; block: any; }>, "htmlType">, "color" | ... 258 more ... | "htmlType"> & Partial<...> & Partial<...>) | ...'.
  Type '{ shape: "circle"; icon: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<NativeButtonProps> & Pick<InferProps<{ type: any; shape: any; size: any; htmlType: any; onClick: any; loading: any; className: any; icon: any; block: any; }>, "htmlType">, "color" | ... 262 more ... | "value">'.
    Property 'htmlType' is missing in type '{ shape: "circle"; icon: string; }'.
```

i can use to {InputNumber} Component in antd
but, i can't {Button} Component because have some this error

what is my mistake ?

App.tsx

```
import { InputNumber, Button } from 'antd';
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import logo from './logo.svg';

class App extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <InputNumber min={1} max={10} defaultValue={3} />
        <Button shape="circle" icon="search" />
        <p className="App">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
 @import '~antd/dist/antd.css';

    .App {
      text-align: center;
    }
...
```

Comment: i add to args in <Button/> Component such as "<Button htmlType="" />
so, i can use to <Button/> Component !!
but.. i met another error [ts] Type ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the module by using the command `npm install  @types/module_name`

OR declare the module in [*.d.ts] file as was stated below

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm solved !

first, you `add to " declare module 'antd' "` in [*.d.ts] file
(ex: ./images.d.ts )

and add to "htmlType" Element
such as.. `<Button type="primary" htmlType="">Primary</Button>`

Typescript is strong code !
so, you can use to new module than you must add to module in [*.d.ts]

and i need your advice for this error
that is Thank's

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Chun-Joo Park

> add to " declare module 'antd' " in [*.d.ts] file (ex: ./images.d.ts )

worked for me, and restart my application

```
yarn start
```